# Windows 10 Tortoise SVN Permission Denied: txn-current-lock

Tags: windows, svn

`Can't open file '/svn/p/thegreatwar/svn/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied`

Hello. Me and my mod team have been using an SVN repository created by a now long-since gone mod member. It has been working flawlessly until today, when, just after attempting to commit changes to a file, the system threw the above error. I've been accessing the repository through svn+ssh.

As with everything that keeps working in spite of a general ignorance on HOW it works, I find myself at a complete loss. Indeed I have no coding knowledge and although I've made a few attempts to copy-paste suggested code snippets from this site into the file settings/subversion/properties thing I'm still no closer to solving the issue.

For what it's worth the only user on this computer has full read/write/etc permissions on the folders involved.

I can't seem to access the file that is causing the issue, either. Someone suggested deleting it in another thread but I can't find the /p folder.

Comment: Is some user's been added recently to access the repository via svn+ssh? Things can go weird if not done properly and the user writes to the repo. Your best bet would be to revert the repo to a recent backup to see if it was a particular commit that broke the perms

Comment: Thanks for replying! No, no users have been added recently. I'll try to revert/update to previous revisions and see what happens.

Comment: Nope, still permission denied sadly!

Comment: The permission denied problem is occuring on the repository itself, not your local machine. Reverting to a previous 'state' (revision) should be done at the server level to see if it helps (backup everything, you know)

Comment: Sorry if I'm being completely oblivious on basic things here - how do I revert on a server level? What I did was I right-clicked my main repository folder and chose 'update to revision', then selected a revision that I know for sure was functional.

Comment: No problem. It's your local machine windows? Since you say you're accesing your repo via svn+ssh, the *server* is likely to be linux and the user you're using to log in to the *server* is having the permission problem on that file. I would take someone with experience in linux sysadmin and subversion take a look on what's going on. Can't help anymore from here ;) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem modulo project name difference. It seems that mine is caused by the ongoing sourceforge.net transfer to the new datacenter, see https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops

If your svn server is also on SF, this might explain your issue.